# 100% height center section using CSS only

Tags: html, css

Here is the JS fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/K6CFU/

The structure is the exact same I'm using for my website but the problem is that I'm not getting the middle section of my site to be 100% high. Right now it's the content that determines how tall it is.

```
<body>
    <div id="page-container">
        <header></header>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div id="page-content">

            </div>
        </div>

        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>

html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

header {    width: 100%;    height: 50px;    background-color: red; }

footer { width: 100%; height: 50px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; background-color: green; }

#page-wrapper { width: 1024px; margin: 0px auto; background-color: yellow; }
#page-content { height: 100%; background-color: pink; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I know what you mean but have you tried adding height:100% to the page-wrapper div?

```
#page-wrapper{ 
 height:100%;
 width: 1024px; 
 margin: 0px auto; 
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem in the past. The way that I see it is that when you specify `height: 100%;`, it fills to 100% of the div (or whatever element) - but not to the screen size. I've always had to use `min-height` somewhere to get similar results that you're seeking.

For the body or probably for your `page-wrapper` div, try specifying `min-height: 500px;` (or whatever you feel is an appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

Make the page-container

```
height: 100%;
```

so that the object inside know the size of the box.

than you can make the page-wrapper

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
top: 50px;
height: auto; /*can also be left away*/
```

now the middle part will be between the footer and the header
http://jsfiddle.net/K6CFU/5/

you can make the page-content

```
height: 100%;
```

or you can leave it away, like you want.